# Database design for inventory with multiple many to many constraints?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, hierarchical-data

I'm trying to design a database architecture for a simple inventory program.

This inventory will consist of items in boxes.  Boxes contain items, and are items themselves.

I imagine `box` will be a super type of `item`.

My main hangup is how to structure/constrain the relation between boxes so that I can still constrain the unique condition that an item can only be in one "place" at a time.

I know that many-to-many relations should let me know which items are in which boxes, but what about boxes that are in other boxes?

For instance:
`Box A` contains `Item B` and `Box C`. `Box C` contains `Item D`.

How can I design a system that when I look for `Item D` I will find it inside `Box A` and `Box C` (really great if I could also know how the relation of the boxes -- latter is inside the former).

Comment: Are you ok to design considering box as item ? In that case you can use Item(PK,FKParent,Type), where FKParent will be constraint to PK. and you can specify Type either Box or Item.

Comment: Your statement " so that I can still constrain the unique condition that an item can only be in one "place" at a time."  seems contradictory to the example How can I design a system that when I look for Item D I will find it inside Box A and Box C. Can you provide more details clearly please..

Comment: @codeLover apologies for any confusion.  When I wrote one "place" I meant that an item cannot be in multiple boxes ~unless~ one of those boxes is inside another.  In the example I gave, `Item D` is inside both `Box A` and `Box C` but this is allowed since `Box C` is inside `Box A`.  Does that clarify?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the self relationship with the table itself. You can mention below mentioned columns in your database design:

```
ItemId(PK)
ItemName
ItemType(Can be B for Box and I for item)
ItemContainer(Will contain ItemId from this table itself and will be null if it is not present in any box, if required add check constraint that if itemType is I then it cannot be null)
```

You can place the data as:

```
ItemId      ItemName      ItemType     ItemContainer
  1         BoxA             B            (null)
  2         BoxB             B               1
  3         ItemA            I               2
```

Since ItemId is a primary key, thus, database will allow only one row per item and thus, it will be available only in one box.

Check if this design helps...

Comment: This seems promising but it seems to allow for recursive locations.  I.e. `BoxA` can have `ItemContainer = 1` and `BoxB` can have `ItemContainer = 2`.

Comment: Can you rephrase your concern please